# Asp.Net Core QueryHelpers AddQueryString does not encode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

One of my query string parameters has the following value:

> name:””[abc]””

which is added to a Dictionary object and is used by the following code:

```
var newUrl = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, myDictionary);
```

When I deploy this code to one computer it works correctly and the newUrl becomes properly encoded:

> api/latest/items?property=name%3A%22%22%5Babc%5D%22%22

However, the same code when deployed to another server does not work and the resulting url is not encoded at all:

> api/latest/items?property=name:””[abc]””

Is there any reason why in one instance the method encodes and in another it doesn’t? (no change in code, same source, same compilation, but only to 2 different servers — one is working and one is not)

Comment: I think you can use this function from javascript 

"var encodedUrl = new Uri(newUrl);"

Comment: `only to 2 different servers` containing which runtime? How did you deploy the web app? Which .NET Core version are you using? The [line that encodes the query string value](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/WebUtilities/src/QueryHelpers.cs#L97) changed *4 years ago*.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in my one project so we have implemented below piece of code. which is helpful for us. you need to encode your url while and decode your URL while fetching value from it.

**Encryption logic :**

```
BaseUrl + "Integration/Link?democode=" + Server.UrlEncode(Crypto.Encrypt(model.demoCode)) + "&requestsource=" + Server.UrlEncode(Crypto.Encrypt(model.demoSource));
```

**Reading Value from Query string :**

```
 Dictionary<string, string> queryStringDic = GetDicFromQueryString(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Request.QueryString))));
```

Below common function will bind your querystring value into Dictionary.

```
 private Dictionary<string, string> GetDicFromQueryString(NameValueCollection queryValue)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryKeyValue = null;
            if (queryValue != null && queryValue.AllKeys != null)
            {
                string value;
                dictionaryKeyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var k in queryValue.AllKeys)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(k))
                    {
                        value = queryValue[k];
                        dictionaryKeyValue.TryAdd(k, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? value : value.Replace(' ', '+'));
                    }
                }
            }
            return dictionaryKeyValue;
        }
```

I hope it will help you. let me know if your still facing issue.